# Part of the 'Bounty Grace Period Started' email uses a default font

Tags: bug, design, bounties, email

A part of the 'Bounty Grace Period Started' uses the system default font. The footer uses the font you chose and the rest of the email looks fine too, so I don't think it's due to lack of support from my email client (Outlook 2016).

See this screenshot:

> [image: screenshot of the email]